# Freetds can't connect to MSSQL

Tags: database, mssql

I had to upgrade to php 7.1 and then my connection to mssql via freetds aren't working

- PHP 7.1.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- SQL Server 2008 r2

The **tsql -C**

tsql -C

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 5.0
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[mssql_db1_freetds]
Driver                  = freetds
Description             = MSSQL Server Stage
Database                = TESTDB1
Server                  = 192.168.0.20
Port                    = 1433
instance                = SQLSRV01


[mssql_db2_freetds]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = 192.168.0.20
Port = 1433
Database = TESTDB2
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount = 1

[Default]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

**/etc/freetds/freetds.conf** (copied in /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf for command line)

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
        timeout = 600
        connect timeout = 600

[mssql_db1_freetds]
    host = 192.168.0.20
    port = 1433
    timeout = 600
    connect timeout = 600
    tds version = 8.0
    text size = 20971520
```

Tryin to connect by tsql

**tsql -S 192.168.0.20 -U test_user -P mypwd** (same with tsql -S mssql_db1_freetds -U test_user -P mypwd)

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
        Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
        OS error 111, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I really don't know whre i'm wrong. SQLSERVER config is not changed.
Thanks

Comment: I've deleted odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini now i can connect via command line but not by my web app (symfony). error is SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (mssql_db1_freetds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed tds version in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf from 8.0 (it worked before php 7.1 upgrade) to 7.0 a typical MSSQL server. Now it works.

Complete config

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[mssql_db1_freetds]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = Db1
ServerName              = mssql_db1_freetds
TDS_Version             = 7.0

[mssql_db2_freetds]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = Db2
ServerName              = mssql_db2_freetds
TDS_Version             = 7.0
```

**/etc/freetds/freetds.conf**

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
        timeout = 600
        connect timeout = 600

[mssql_db1_freetds]
    host = 192.168.0.20
    port = 1433
    timeout = 600
    connect timeout = 600
    tds version = 7.0
    text size = 20971520

[mssql_db2_freetds]
    host = 192.168.0.20
    port = 1433
    timeout = 600
    connect timeout = 600
    tds version = 7.0
    text size = 20971520
```